# how to map a command in command line

Tags: vim

I often used the command of

```
vimgrep /abce/ c:/branchA/scripts/**/*.sql
```

But that's too long

How can I have a mapping as:

```
:mf abc
```

then it will be convert to automatically?

```
vimgrep /abce/ c:/branchA/scripts/**/*.sql
```

Answer (score 0):

This is best done with a custom command, not a mapping (assuming you don't want to further edit the command-line):

```
command! -nargs=1 Mf vimgrep /<args>/ c:/branchA/scripts/**/*.sql
```

As a custom command, it has to start with an uppercase letter. The argument is inserted with the `<args>` special keyword.